# can i make a while loop if a var is neither any of 4 values?

Tags: c#, while-loop, var

First of all sorry for the question if it sounds stupid (just started programming), and im not very good at english.

So, i want to make a while loop that activates when a var is neither any of 4 string values.
something like this:
 `while(var != ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4"]){`
And i would like to know how to write it, or another way to do it.
thanks.

Comment: Where do the strings come from? Are they hardcoded?

Comment: does `var` refer to implicit type or a variable in this context?

Comment: @rainydevbs The OP is just giving an example I think, it's pseudocode.

Comment: Did you try that code?  What was the result?  This is really "How do I test if one value is among a set of other values?", then inverted and combined with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are hardcoded, the "dumb" way to do this is:

```
while (var != "str1" && var != "str2"...) {
```

If the strings are part of a collection, you could likely use `collection.Contains(var)` or something like that.

Another way is an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
    public static bool In<T>(this T t, params T[] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (t.Equals(array[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Then you could just do `var.In("str1", "str2", "str3", "str4")`.

Comment: What about `Contains` from `System.Linq`? Any reason why this wouldn't be a candidate instead of creating a new extension method?

Comment: @ColinM I mention that in my answer.

Comment: I apologise, this is what I get for skim reading. +1 for keeping the array as this could also be populated from a config file or data source.

Comment: Definitely a nice solution to be sure, but wouldn't this be a little bit overkill? As far as their experience and what they're trying to accomplish, it might be a bit overwhelming. (Like I said though, it's a good solution for the problem, I don't mean to cast aspersions.)

Answer (score 1):

I think with Linq you could accomplish something like this:

```
var invalid = new string[]{ "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4"};
var value = Console.ReadLine();

while(!invalid.Contains(value))
{
    // whatever you need inside the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you as you are new to programming

while(condition1 && condition2 && ....) would be clear.

But if the no of strings increases exponentially than
write a function that return true or false and call that as condition for while loop
ex bool function(val)
{
   //SOS
   return true only if not equal to all the strings 
   else
     return false

}
and in while loop

while(function(v))

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("--Start--");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value:");
        var x = Console.ReadLine();
        while(x != "a" && x != "b" && x != "c" && x != "d")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try again");
            x = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("--End--");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is neither any of 4 string values

Actually this can be almost literally translated into linq C# code:

```
string [] set = new string[]{ "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4"};

while (!set.Any(x => x == myValue))
{
    // ...
}
```